# What XSD data type to use for arbitrary XML data in my web service?

Tags: java, xsd, spring-ws

I am writing a web service using Spring-WS to transfer XML data. What XSD data type should I use to define the arbitrary XML data that I intend to send back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xsd:any`. Read [extensible content models](http://www.xfront.com/ExtensibleContentModels.html#method2). You can also read [Catch All Element Pattern](http://www.xmlpatterns.com/CatchAllElementMain.shtml)